# Arguments in mysql_select_db

Tags: php

Having problems with the arguments in the mysql_select_db

```
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, my_database);
```

The second argument is supposed to be the name of the DB (according to W3S)

However, on run I get

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant my_database - assumed 'my_database' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cag\func.php on line 84
```

Am I interpreting this error correctly. Or is some other issue at play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "my_database");
```

or
Better way

$database="name of database";

```
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your name in quotes (""), or store it in a variable: `$temp = "my_database"`